# Crash when debug sources after install Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcode7, xcode6.4, xcode7-beta6

Seems there is an issue right now. I am trying to debug sources in Xcode 6, but when I get a line where I put breakpoint Xcode 6 unexpectedly crashes.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning out DerivedData? Left over intermediate build products from Xcode 6 might cause Xcode 7 to choke.

Comment: @algal, I will try this, thanks

Comment: @algal, your suggestion works, thank you!